# The downloadablePlot shiny module is not displayed in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, downloadableplot

I have the `shiny` app below and I would like to know how I can download a plot using the `downloadablePlot` Shiny Module. When I launch the app I get `Error in visibleplot: could not find function "visibleplot"`. It is supposed to be loaded via the `shiny` package and the button is not displayed.

```
library(shiny)
library(periscope)
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot"),
  downloadablePlotUI("object_id1", 
                     downloadtypes = c("png", "csv"), 
                     download_hovertext = "Download the plot and data here!",
                     height = "500px", 
                     btn_halign = "left")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot<-renderPlot(plot(iris))
  plotInput = function() {
    plot(iris)
  }
  callModule(downloadablePlot,
             "object_id1", 
             logger = ss_userAction.Log,
             filenameroot = "mydownload1",
             aspectratio = 1.33,
             downloadfxns = list(png = plotInput),
             visibleplot = plotInput)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on `downloadablePlotUI` states the following:

This module is NOT compatible with the built-in (base) graphics (any functions provided by the graphics package such as plot) because they cannot be saved into an object and are directly output by the system at the time of creation.

You are using plot(iris) which cannot be displayed.

Using `ggplot` will display the plot.  I am still not getting the download button.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot<-renderPlot(plotInput())
  plotInput <- function() {
    ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist))+geom_point()
  }
  plot <- ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist))+geom_point()
  callModule(downloadablePlot,
             "object_id1", 
             logger = ss_userAction.Log,
             filenameroot = "mydownload1",
             aspectratio = 1.33,
             downloadfxns = list(png = plotInput),
             visibleplot = plotInput )
  
}
```